# Library `Coroutines' not found in list of llvm libraries

Tags: cmake, llvm, ubuntu-16.04, coroutine, llvm-clang

I'm trying to setup `LLVM release version 3.5` on my `ubuntu 16.04` LTS 64-bit machine, and have been facing errors related to `CMake`.

How to solve: `` Library `Coroutines' not found in list of llvm libraries `` ?

1. I followed instructions given [here](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary), to the T.
2. I got the following error log on executing `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm`

   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:27: fatal error: malloc/malloc.h: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_23510.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_23510.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_23510.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1

   ...

   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:18: fatal error: ndir.h: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_a8c89.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_a8c89.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_a8c89.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1

   ...

   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:22: fatal error: sys/ndir.h: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_9297d.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_9297d.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_9297d.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1

   ...

   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:31: fatal error: valgrind/valgrind.h: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_14b5f.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_14b5f.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_14b5f.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1

   ...

   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:18: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_a4254.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_a4254.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_a4254.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1

   ...

   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:23: fatal error: mach/mach.h: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_43c90.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_43c90.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_43c90.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1

   ...

   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:25: fatal error: mach-o/dyld.h: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_92df8.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_92df8.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_92df8.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1

   ...

   /usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=compress2    CMakeFiles/cmTC_45dee.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_45dee -rdynamic -lz -lm 
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_45dee.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_45dee' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [cmTC_45dee] Error 1

   ...

   /usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=el_init    CMakeFiles/cmTC_678de.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_678de -rdynamic -ledit -lm 
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ledit
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_678de.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_678de' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [cmTC_678de] Error 1

   ...

   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltinfo
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_b7cfe.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_b7cfe' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [cmTC_b7cfe] Error 1

   ...

   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lterminfo
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_58a1c.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_58a1c' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [cmTC_58a1c] Error 1

   ...

   /usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=setupterm    CMakeFiles/cmTC_adafa.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_adafa -rdynamic -lcurses -lm 
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurses
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_adafa.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_adafa' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [cmTC_adafa] Error 1

   ...

   /usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=setupterm    CMakeFiles/cmTC_e466b.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_e466b -rdynamic -lncurses -lm 
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_e466b.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_e466b' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [cmTC_e466b] Error 1

   ...

   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncursesw
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_8dc06.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_8dc06' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [cmTC_8dc06] Error 1

   ...

   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:8:19: error: ‘arc4random’ undeclared (first use in this function)
      return ((int*)(&arc4random))[argc];
                      ^
   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:8:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_75c3b.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_75c3b.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_75c3b.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o] Error 1

   ...

   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:2:17: fatal error: cmath: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_53670.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_53670.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_53670.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o] Error 1

   ...

   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:2:20: fatal error: ieeefp.h: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_e4e6e.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_e4e6e.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_e4e6e.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o] Error 1

   ...

   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:2:17: fatal error: cmath: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_b8170.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_b8170.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_b8170.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o] Error 1

   ...

   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:8:19: error: ‘exp10’ undeclared (first use in this function)
      return ((int*)(&exp10))[argc];
                      ^
   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:8:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_392cf.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_392cf.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_392cf.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o] Error 1

   ...

   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:2:27: fatal error: malloc/malloc.h: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_ff0fe.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_ff0fe.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_ff0fe.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o] Error 1

   ...

   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:8:19: error: ‘strerror_s’ undeclared (first use in this function)
      return ((int*)(&strerror_s))[argc];
                      ^
   /home/.../llvm_dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:8:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
   CMakeFiles/cmTC_97097.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_97097.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o' failed
   make[1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary): *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_97097.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o] Error 1

   ...
3. A similar error was faced before and posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772617/building-llvm-fails-with-empty-error-message). But since my Python version was of 2.7x series, this didn't help.
4. So going by the log above, I started with the simpler one, installing `Valgrind`.
5. After re-trying the command `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm`

to see if it's solving errors: I've been getting the `Library Coroutines` error ever since, and I am stuck.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a workaround.
Installed `clang-3.5` and `llvm-3.5` using the `sudo apt install` method.